# Add PHP Runtime library to PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I have Laravel project and I'm working on it in the PhpStorm.

On the company computer, everything is good, but on the home computer I do not have PHP Runtime library in External Libraries. Because of this code autocompletion does not work.

How can I fix this problem? I don't know how to add this library.

P.S. Laravel plugin was installed.

[image]

Comment: voted to close because it should be asked on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Luceos, not necessarily. You can ask about tools used for programming here on stack overflow.

Comment: And, direcly to OP, are you sure this is not a library built by your company? Perhaps this is why you cannot find it.

Comment: First time seeing such issue. 1) Close IDE 2) Go to project folder 3) Delete `.idea` subfolder (this project settings) 4) Open IDE again 5) Use `Open` and point to project root folder -- IDE will create fresh project from those files and should init it correctly with PHP Runtime this time.

Comment: I think it was added with recent PhpStorm upgrade.

Comment: What is PhpStorm version on your home computer?

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes no, it is not company library.

Comment: @artspb 
PhpStorm 2016.2.2
Build #PS-162.2380.11, built on October 24, 2016

Comment: @LazyOne I deleted .ide folder in project, but it did not help http://take.ms/BnYZW

Comment: @J.Menshov It was added in **2016.3** only (ability to use your own stubs & the way how it displayed in GUI). Before it was all internal. Please upgrade (or at least try) 2016.3 and check how it will behave there. Here is original ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30134

Comment: @J.Menshov Yes, LazyOne is right, stubs were added to the tree in 2016.3. But still, completion has to work in 2016.2. Could you please provide a code sample where completion works in 2016.3, but doesn't work in 2016.2?